# Como evitar que la siguiente imagen sea igual a la anterior?

Tags: php, html

intento mostrar una url de unas imágenes, pero quiero que cada vez que de botón derecha o izquierda
se muestre una imagen diferente a la anterior randomizada. He conseguido hacerlo con cookies, pero hay otra manera de hacerlo mejor o otra manera sin usar cookies ?

Este es el código:

```
if(isset($_COOKIE["primera"]) && isset($_COOKIE["anterior"]))
{
    $anterior = $_COOKIE["anterior"];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM photos where urlPath != '$anterior' ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1"; // carga una imagen que sea diferente a la anterior
    $preparada = $db->prepare($sql);
    $preparada->execute();
        
    if($preparada)
    {
        echo '<table>';
        foreach ($preparada as $fila) 
        {
            setcookie("anterior", $fila["urlPath"], time() + 1800); // 30 minutos

            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>' . $fila["urlPath"] . '</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
        }
        echo '</table>';
    }
}
else if(isset($_COOKIE["primera"])) // si la primera ya la ha visto, genera una nueva diferente a la primera
{
    $anterior = $_COOKIE["primera"];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM photos where urlPath != '$anterior' ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1"; // carga una imagen que sea diferente a la anterior
    $preparada = $db->prepare($sql);
    $preparada->execute();
        
    if($preparada)
    {
        echo '<table>';
        foreach ($preparada as $fila) 
        {
            setcookie("anterior", $fila["urlPath"], time() + 1800); // 30 minutos

            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>' . $fila["urlPath"] . '</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
        }
        echo '</table>';
    }
}
// mirar si es la primera vez que entra (crear cookie con la url de la ultima imagen subida)
else if(!(isset($_COOKIE["primera"])))
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM photos where pubDate = (SELECT MAX(pubdate) from photos)";
    // $sql = "SELECT * FROM photos ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1"; // carga una imagen que sea diferente a la anterior
    $preparada = $db->prepare($sql);
    $preparada->execute();
        
    if($preparada)
    {
        echo '<table>';
        foreach ($preparada as $fila) 
        {
            setcookie("primera", $fila["urlPath"], time() + 1800); // 30 minutos

            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>' . $fila["urlPath"] . '</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
        }
        echo '</table>';
    }
}
```

He estado probando con variables, pero pasa que cuando carga la imagen, ya que es por método POST, pues esa variable se resetea, y lo único que se me ha ocurrido es guardarlo en cookies, pero también puede que el usuario elimine esas cookies por lo que se dejarían de mostrar. Un dilema.

Comment: Puedes intentar usar javascript, así evitas hacer tantas peticiones al back. Tendrías que cargar tu listado de url o si son muchas, cargas un sub conjunto de ellas y las vas mostrando con un evento en los botones de izquierda y derecha.

Comment: no se mucho de javascript, apenas hemos empezado con php

Comment: Hola Wail, lee sobre cómo asociar los parámetros en sentencias preparadas en PHP. Estás usando sentencias preparadas, pero luego realmente generas la sentencia dinámicamente y de una forma insegura que hace el código vulnerable a ataques de inyección SQL.